# How to get table prefix?

Tags: magento-1.9, table, prefix

I have the following code in my install to create a table:

```
$installer->run(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `npcallnations_orders` (
        `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `order` int,
        `status` int,
        `real_order_id` int,
        `customer` varchar(245),
        `fatdir` int,
        `created_at` DATETIME null,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )"
);
```

but if the magento has a table prefix, it will return an error when I try to use the collection. How can I do it so it will create correctly with prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('npcallnations_orders')
```

Comment: where exactly...?

Comment: Replace npcallnations_orders by that